# Joomla Login Error : Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet

Tags: joomla

When a new user registers for my Joomla site, after activating his/her account via activation email link , he's unable to login to my site..This error gets displayed : Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet ? i can check from my backend that the user status is ACTIVATED but still he's not able to login? Plus i read somewhere that we have to make sure password generation/reset uses the MD5 encryption & the problem will be solved in this file : `libraries/joomla/user/helper.php` . More precisely it was written that they added the following line to the beginning of the hashPassword function in this `libraries/joomla/user/helper.php` file:

`return md5($password);` and the problem was fixed. can any body guide me!

Comment: What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: What exact version of Joomla! are you using? Have you updated it to the latest minor version?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but about Joomla and should be asked on the [Joomla StackExchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Comment: What's interesting? 
-> when i registered from frontend and set the password to read , this value was found in _users table f0bb7564f8c84d1cbdada8dc04493be2

-> & when i set the password to read using Joomla backend, this value was found in _users table 0edda82c8ad9aa4da0dfe3b64f249c18:dqRwd90MzB21LP8waOjW0XEQzt4LSZoE and the login was successful?

Comment: Can you please answer the questions you have been asked, we have good reasons for asking them. Also you'll find many versions of this question here and also on http://docs.joomla.org and http://forum.joomla.org.

Comment: I had the same issue after updating 2.5.14 to 2.5.28 and this solved the issue: http://www.itoctopus.com/username-and-password-do-not-match-or-you-do-not-have-an-account-yet-error-cause-and-fix